# Area of square created by intersection of segments from a square vertexes to their opposite sides

Tags: geometry

There will be an square created when we draw segments from a square vertexes to their opposite sides' middle.

[image: I mean the gray area]

What is the relation between smaller square's area and the side length of the bigger one?

Comment: Are the sides divided into equal lengths?

Comment: yes, I'm sorry I forgot that!

Comment: The area of the square is one fifth the area of the larger square

Comment: is there a clear reason for "line segment from D to DE∩CH is also a"?

Comment: that is not correct. I will post my solution late but the length is not equal to a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a$ be the side length of the grey square (and $1$ the side lengthg of the original square).
By similarity, the length of the line segment from $D$ to $DE\cap CH$ is also $a$.
Then the triangle with base $AE$ complete the quadrilateral with top edge $DE$ to a square of area $a^2$. We can do the same with the other triangles and conclude that $1^2= 5a^2$.

Comment: That's right, but please explain why sum of areas of little rectangles and quadrilaterals is equal to area of the smaller square? (or why is line segment from D to DE∩CH is also a)

Comment: could you please? :D

Comment: Let intersection of DE and CH be X, DE and AG be Y. Since CH and AG are parallel, and H midpoint of AD, then by similar triangles X is midpoint of DY.